# Let a ViewModel know when the user scrolled to the end of a ListView in XAML with MVVM

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, fetch

Is there a easy way to do this? The internet has a few samples but not for MVVM Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime apps.

My ListView has originally 20 items and when a user scrolls to the end, another 20 items needs to be loaded. But how do I let my ViewModel know the end of the ListView is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a Helper class that's implemented in the [WinRT Xaml](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) Toolkit you can get a reference to the vertical `scrollBar` inside the `ListView` control, then attach an event handler to it, to helps you detect when you the bottom of the `ListView` is reached, util know all that will be implemented in the code behind of your page, (that't won't violate any mvvm rule since this is a view related logic ) and once the bottom is reached w'll send a `NotificationMessage` to the Page's ViewModel using the Mvvm-light `Messenger` class, here how to do that in steps :

**Step 1**

add the following helper class (from Xaml toolkit) to your project, it has some extension methods and will get you access to the scroll bar:

```
public static class VisualTreeHelperExtensions
{
    public static T GetFirstDescendantOfType<T>(this DependencyObject start) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        return start.GetDescendantsOfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetDescendantsOfType<T>(this DependencyObject start) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        return start.GetDescendants().OfType<T>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetDescendants(this DependencyObject start)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(start);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(start, i);
            yield return child;
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var parent = queue.Dequeue();
            var count2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

            for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                yield return child;
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
    }

    public static T GetFirstAncestorOfType<T>(this DependencyObject start) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        return start.GetAncestorsOfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAncestorsOfType<T>(this DependencyObject start) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        return start.GetAncestors().OfType<T>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetAncestors(this DependencyObject start)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(start);

        while (parent != null)
        {
            yield return parent;
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
    }

    public static bool IsInVisualTree(this DependencyObject dob)
    {
        return Window.Current.Content != null && dob.GetAncestors().Contains(Window.Current.Content);
    }

    public static Rect GetBoundingRect(this FrameworkElement dob, FrameworkElement relativeTo = null)
    {
        if (relativeTo == null)
        {
            relativeTo = Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement;
        }

        if (relativeTo == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Element not in visual tree.");
        }

        if (dob == relativeTo)
            return new Rect(0, 0, relativeTo.ActualWidth, relativeTo.ActualHeight);

        var ancestors = dob.GetAncestors().ToArray();

        if (!ancestors.Contains(relativeTo))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Element not in visual tree.");
        }

        var pos =
            dob
                .TransformToVisual(relativeTo)
                .TransformPoint(new Point());
        var pos2 =
            dob
                .TransformToVisual(relativeTo)
                .TransformPoint(
                    new Point(
                        dob.ActualWidth,
                        dob.ActualHeight));

        return new Rect(pos, pos2);
    }
}
```

**Step 2**

add the `listView` to your xaml and a Loaded event handler,

```
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Loaded="MainPage_OnLoaded">  
    <Grid>
        <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" x:Name="ListV"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</common:PageBase>
```

**Step 3**

In your page code behind add the required handlers

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = ListV.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
        var scrollbars = scrollViewer.GetDescendantsOfType<ScrollBar>().ToList();
        var verticalBar = scrollbars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical);
        if (verticalBar != null)
            verticalBar.Scroll += BarScroll;
    }
    async void BarScroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ScrollEventType != ScrollEventType.EndScroll) return;

        var bar = sender as ScrollBar;
        if (bar == null)
            return;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Scrolling ended");

        if (e.NewValue >= bar.Maximum)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We are at the bottom");
            Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage("LoadMore"));                
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We are away from the bottom");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code notice that once the bottom is detected w'll send a `NotificationMessage` using the `Messenger` class

```
 Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage("LoadMore"));
```

**Step 4**

in the page's View model add the code that load new items to the ListView once the notification message is received

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<String> _itemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
        "Item 4"        
    };

    public ObservableCollection<String> ItemsCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemsCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_itemsCollection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _itemsCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public async Task LoadMoreItems()
    {
        ItemsCollection.Add("Item " + ItemsCollection.Count);
        ItemsCollection.Add("Item " + ItemsCollection.Count);
        ItemsCollection.Add("Item " + ItemsCollection.Count);
        ItemsCollection.Add("Item " + ItemsCollection.Count);
        ItemsCollection.Add("Item " + ItemsCollection.Count);

    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {   
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, async m =>
        {
            switch (m.Notification)
            {
                case "LoadMore":
                    await LoadMoreItems();
                    break;

            }
        });
    }  
}
```

The credit of how to detect the bottom goes to the following [article](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/winrt-xaml-automatically-scrolling-listview-to-bottom-and-detecting-when-listview-is-scrolled) .

**UPDATE**

Indeed as mentioned in the comments the above code works perfectly on a WinRt Store app but for some reason it won't work on a windows phone (winrt 8.1) projects, and it looks like the `scroll` event in the vertical `ScrollBar` isn't firing for some reason, i have a workaround for that, instead handle the `ViewChanged` event of the `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListView`, change the code behind of your page to the following :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = ListV.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
        scrollViewer.ViewChanged+=BarScroll;          
    }

    private void BarScroll(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollbars = (sender as ScrollViewer).GetDescendantsOfType<ScrollBar>().ToList();
        var verticalBar = scrollbars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical);
        if (verticalBar.Value >= verticalBar.Maximum)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We are at the bottom");
            Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage("LoadMore"));
        }           
    }        
}
```

and keep the rest as it is.

Comment: Hey, this looks great yes! But when I scroll to the bottom nothing happens. App never comes in "async void BarScroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)".

Comment: Btw this code is autoscrolling to the bottom of the ListView?

Comment: hi @Bayern I've obviously tried the approach i am describing before posting  my answer and it works perfectly at my end https://gyazo.com/8381c92515b437f9245327b8021ff3ee
the only difference is that i'am using a winrt store app instead on a windows phone app (due to some hardware limitation in my machine ), and the code I've posted should works on both store and phone app, i will upload the sample project to oneDrive so you can get a better sample project to customize, then tell me if the issue persists

Comment: There you go https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=837568D051BAD7CE!2785&authkey=!ADnVt4-S25pznuI&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: thank you very much and indeed your sample works, but when I copy that code into a windows phone it doesn't seem to work. When I set a breakpoint in the "MainPage_OnLoaded" method it breaks there, but doesn't come into "async void BarScroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)"

Comment: i see, i could probably be missing something, i will try to run the code on an actual WP device once i get one tomorrow, then i will update the code to fix the issue (if there is)

Comment: HI @Bayern, you were right, check the update on the answer for a workaround, i am not sure why exactly this happening i will investigate that once i get some time.

Comment: Yay! Nice it works! Thank you so much! Is it normal that when I add it to my existing project that "System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We are at the bottom");" is printed twice everytime?

Comment: sorry but I really can't figure this out why it triggers twice everytime I scroll to the end of my ListView :S

Comment: none of that happens to me, make sure you are not handling the event twice, https://gyazo.com/15eac2999f6be63639e1a224b8433122

Comment: Yes, if I use your code in a new Windows Phone 8.1 Project it runs like in that video, but when I implement it into my existing project for some reason when I scoll to the bottom, the event is triggerd twice every time :p strange!

Comment: Ok I found a probably ugly solution. if (((_Teller % 2) == 0) && (verticalBar.Value >= verticalBar.Maximum)), So now it fires the event only once :D. Anyway thank you for this code you provided!

Comment: hey is it possible to put a ScrollViewer arround my ListView and trigger when the ScrollViewer is at the bottom?

Comment: I tried this var scrollViewer = ActivitiesListView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ListView>();
            var scroll = scrollViewer.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();  It seems that a ScrollViewer arround a Listview is smooter, then i have no black background when i scroll fast. But then it wont trigger the end of the list anymore :/

Answer (score 4):

If your case is loading more items when reaching the end of the list to create "lazy loading", then take a look at `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface. It is an interface that you implement in your collection and the `ListView` automatically uses it to load more items when end reached. Here is an example: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/implementing-the-isupportincrementalloading-interface-in-a-window-store-app/.

I personally do not like this approach, having a collection that knows how to load data. There is a `ExtendedListViewControl` (http://www.tareqateik.com/extendedlistview-control-for-universal-apps-pull-to-refresh-load-more-data-on-demand)  created by Tareq Ateik firing an event when the end of the list is reached. So when the event is fired, handle it in your ViewModel (if you use Caliburn.Micro you can "subscribe" to the event directly), or use messaging to send a message to the ViewModel.

Or just handle the event in code behind and call the desired method on your ViewModel from code-behind.

Comment: @Igor Kulman ok I will take a look at it, thank you. But actualy the only thing I need is to send something to my ViewModel when the end of the ListView is reached, then from there on I do another api call with a different startindex.

Comment: then go with the ExtendedListViewControl, it fires an event when the end of the list is reached

Comment: @IgorKulman is it possible to use MoreDataRequested in MVVM light? Like this: <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="MoreDataRequested">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RequestMoreActivities}" />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

Comment: @IgorKulman there is no EvenToCommand in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime, here they make use of Behaviors, but "MoreDataRequested" is not a supported EventName like Loaded or Tapped or Unchecked.

Comment: "MoreDataRequested" = ExtendedListView.MoreDataRequested and all other events like "Loaded", "Tapped" = UIElement.(name of event).

Comment: If the event isn't being picked up bij the EventTriggerBehavior, you could always trap it in the code behind and send a message for the ViewModel. Or you could create your own extendedlistview, the code to detect the end scroll is visible here: https://github.com/mikoskinen/blog/blob/master/WinRT-XAML-ListView-Autoscroll/WinRT-XAML-ListView-Autoscroll/MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: @Depechie how exactly then?

Comment: The example seeks the scrollviewer inside the list and subscribes to it's events to determine if you reached the end. Take a peek :)

Comment: Or just handle the event in code behind and call the desired method on your ViewModel from code-behind. Simple and easy. And acceptable if you are not a total MVVM purist :)

Comment: @IgorKulman yes I was thinking doing something like that. But "MoreDataRequested" expects a return type... And how exactly do you trigger something on a ViewModel from codebehind? Use Messenger?

Comment: the dirty way would be (this.DataContext as YourViewModel).MethodCall. The return type is a Task, is ideally if you MethodCall returns a task, should be a good match for a method loading data.

Comment: @IgorKulman xD I really appriciate your help, and I know its friday evening, but could you provade a little sample code :p?

Comment: Okay I finnaly managed to load more items.... But omg that ExtendedListView is bugged xD it lagges at the top of the ListView..... It doesn't run smootly at the top..

Comment: The go with the firts choice, using a custom collection with ISupportIncrementalLoading